# Getting a traceback from a exceptions without re-raising them

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I'm using Twister to build a server. I am also maintaining a server error log. The issue is that if I let an exception run all the way up the stack, it'll crash the current connection and disconnect the user, so obviously I attach a bare except to grab everything else.

Once I've caught something, is there a way to get the traceback as a string so that I can store it somewhere/print it myself without raising it and letting Python print it for me once the program crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback module contains some helper functions for printing and inspecting the traceback (for exameble, traceback.print_tb ) - but the important thing is that the traceback information itself is stored in a "interpreter global" variable - sys.exc_traceback, on the module sys.

Quoting from:

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#try

> Before an except clause’s suite is executed, details about the
>   exception are assigned to three variables in the sys module:
>   sys.exc_type receives the object identifying the exception;
>   sys.exc_value receives the exception’s parameter; sys.exc_traceback
>   receives a traceback object...

You can pass the sys.exc_traceback object as a parameter to traceback.print_tb to have the traceback printed to stdout within the except clause.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#module-logging), you could [log the traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) to a file:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, filename = logfile)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as err:
    logger.exception(err)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import traceback, sys

try:
    # Do something that might raise an exception
    open("/does not exist",'rb')
except:
    traceback.print_exc( file=sys.stderr )
    # Or 
    traceback.print_exc( file=your_open_log_file )
```

That should do the trick and print full stack traces too.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there's a [module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) for that. The `traceback` module contains functions to print or format exception information, or to return the raw stack frames so you can do whatever you want with them.

For a reasonably sophisticated application, though, I would actually recommend using the logging system instead of plain old `traceback` functions. In particular the method [`logging.Logger.exception`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) will write information about the exception to whatever logging destination you (or your software's user) has configured. The default formatter will just print out a traceback, as Python would on the console, but you can customize the display of exceptions in your log by creating a `Formatter` and overriding the [`format_exception`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException) method. Your overridden method is the place to call `traceback` functions if you need them to format the exception output.